Can a math major get into quantum computing?
I was wondering if by doing a math major I could get into quantum computing and no, doing a degree in physics is not an option sadly.
I also want to know if being a software engineer would be a better option than majoring in math to enter into quantum computing.
I would also love to know how much physics I need to know for learning quantum computing.

Welcome to QCSE. Right now your question is kind of opinionated, and it might be hard to answer in this forum. I do know that the qiskit team has put out some good videos on what backgrounds are good for quantum computing. I’d point you to, e.g., here. Good luck!

Quantum computing is a very interdisciplinary field, involving mathematicians, physicists, computer scientists, engineers, material scientists,...
Personally, I started out as a physicist, got my PhD in Applied Maths/Theoretical Physics and am now based in a maths department. Of the 4 PhD students I currently have, 3 are mathematicians. That shapes the sort of project I do with them - on average they might be missing some skills you would expect a physicist to have (while all being individuals with different leanings), but they make up for it in other ways, particularly their technical skills.
You can learn to do the maths of quantum computing with very little physics. A couple of basic axioms, and you're away. It takes time to build up intuition about what can work/doesn't work and I would suggest that having already studied physics gets you a head start on that, but it's not a problem (depending on what precisely it is you want to work on).
